# bootstrap multiselect onchange events on select all

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using boostrap multiselect in javascript for generating multiselect drop down. There is country field and one state. when country is select is triggers on on chnage event which populates all states related to select country for which i through a AJAX call. thing is if all is selected in country it is firing onchange event for every country which causes lots of AJAX call. For multiple select I am sending selected country codes in comma separated form. So if i can get only one final onchange event i can pull all the data. any idea how i can implement.

Comment: Don't use the `onchange` event then. Instead fetch all selected values on submit.

Comment: jsfiddle.net Fiddle pls.